# What are the differences between GC and PS2 port of Viewtiful Joe?

Tags: version-differences, viewtiful-joe

I'm not able to find sufficient information about what the differences are between the PS2 port and the original GC version of *Viewtiful Joe*.

Can anyone give me a complete account of what has been changed in the PS2 port from the original? For example, I know that the graphics have been affected somewhat. In what way? I know there's a new difficulty added, which one is it? And is the original difficulty level still preserved? How does the control mapping to a PS2 pad work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found [this](http://www.neo-geo.com/forums/showthread.php?105464-Viewtiful-Joe-PS2-vs-GC) (<- click)

A user of this forum seems to have both versions and listed the pros:

> Well, I've owned the GC version and I currently own the PS2 version.
>
> GC pros:
>    Faster loading times
>    Smoother graphics/almost no slowdown
>
> PS2 pros:
>   Extra playable character Dante
>   A new difficulty, "Sweet," it's the easiest difficulty in the game
>   Better unlockable music video

I hope you are still interested in the answer.

Comment: Thank you, Tonsenson. I am still interested. Very good information, thanks!